# Adding the Custom Framework gives the error in Invalid Code Signing Entitlements while Archiving

Tags: macos

I have finished an App using a custom Framework(Drawkit). Everything works fine. I tried to submit the app to app store. When I archive the app for the Mac App Store I am getting this error.

```
Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. The entitlements in your app bundle signature do not match the ones that are contained in the provisioning profile. According to the provisioning profile, the bundle contains a key value that is not allowed.:
989NCWK54P.com.username.InAppPurcahaseExampleMac' for the key 'com.apple.application-identifier' in 'SampleProject.app/Contents/MacOS/SampleProject'

Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. The entitlements in your app bundle signature do not match the ones that are contained in the provisioning profile. According to the provisioning profile, the bundle contains a key value that is not allowed:
'989NCWK54P.com.username.InAppPurchaseExampleMac' for the key 'com.apple.application-identifier' in 'SampleProject.app/Contents/Resources/CGDrawKit.framework/Versions/A/GCDrawkit'
```

I get this error only when I add a Custom Framework in my app otherwise I am not getting this error. I compiled the Drawkit with the provisional Profile. Also there is no key like `"com.apple.application-identifier"` in my Entitlements file. I don't know how to fix this issue and submit the app to app Store. I tried all the solutions given in Stackoverflow.
[image]